# Service Oriented (headless) approach

Tags: 8

We've been managing a Drupal 6 based content rich site for almost 8 years now. Now, client is planning to move from Drupal 6 and seek out different possibilities. What they want is a service oriented approach so that the site can provide services to the end points like any 3rd party or a mobile app. The UI can be built with any available JS framework (angular etc.).

While thinking of this, we came up with using Drupal 8 as the underlying framework. 
The a very basic architecture diagram is as follows:
[image]
There are some PROS & CONS to consider.

**Why Drupal**

- Since the site is in D6, it will be easy to migrate to D8 compared to other frameworks like Laravel or Symfony.
- Drupal provides many functionalities out of the box (we all know it).
- Drupal 8 has REST support in CORE.
- Drupal 8 overcomes headless hurdle compared to it's predecessor.

**Why we are not feeling lucky**

This is where I need some help from the members in this forum.

- Drupal 8 views rest_export provides a JSON representation but how to restrict fields? Say, I don't want to display the body field in the response.
- How to implement custom Rest web services in Drupal 8?
- Is it possible to version the API? Say, `api.example.com/v1`, `api.example.com/v2` and keep both so that other 3rd party can use any.
- How mature is Drupal 8's REST API before Drupal 8.2.x? There are many issues in the issue queue for REST.

Comment: I'm just going to make the comment that Drupal Answers isn't a forum; it's a Q&A knowledge base. The difference being is the focus on a short, answerable Q&A format at the expense of long discussion. You should break your questions into separate posts each focused only on each bullet point at the end.  I'll also note that bullet #4 might be flagged as opinion based (e.g. different issues might be dealbreakers depending on your own requirements, "how mature" depends on your perspective).

Comment: @ShawnConn: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I do know this is a Q&A KB. I refereed this as forum in a common sense "where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged". :-)
I'll try to break the queries to different posts but I doubt those will help the cause.
Thanks though!!